# git commit id placed into POM memory doesn't go into manifest

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to coerce my Maven build to produce a line like this in the manifest of the resulting jar file:

```
SCM-Revision: fdf7abe874a0a54f580aec96da366c168446378c
```

such that the value is the git commit id.

So, I found [this plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin), and I followed the instructions for setting it up.  The verbose output and the ant run output looks fine, but the resulting manifest file just has the raw property reference, not the substituted string.

This is what I have in the parent pom for my multiproject build:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>revision</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                <failOnNoGitDirectory>true</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                <injectAllReactorProjects>true</injectAllReactorProjects>
                <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/../../.git</dotGitDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <SCM-Revision>${git.commit.id}, ${gitCommit}</SCM-Revision>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo>Git-Infos: ${git.commit.id}, ${gitCommit}</echo>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Because I was doing other experiments to get this to work, I also defined the following in an earlier "properties" section:

```
    <gitCommit>${git.commit.id}</gitCommit>
```

When I run the build, I see this in the output, along with the verbose output from the plugin:

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) @ usl-shared ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [echo] Git-Infos: fdf7abe874a0a54f580aec96da366c168446378c, fdf7abe874a0a54f580aec96da366c168446378c
[INFO] Executed tasks
```

However, this is what I get in the manifest file in the jar:

```
SCM-Revision: ${git.commit.id}, ${git.commit.id}
```

Somehow the property reference(s) in the jar plugin didn't substitute the property values.

**Update**:

I also note that the git.properties file was created in target/classes, but it's not in the jar file.  This implies that the file was created after the jar file was created, which implies that those properties were set after the jar file was created, making this behavior understandable.  This sounds like a problem with the "phase".  I'm using the recommended configuration for this, but it sure seems like that would be the problem.

**Update**:

I don't know if this is relevant, but note that the packaging type of our artifact projects is "bundle", not "jar".  We also use the maven-bundle-plugin.  I tried as a test to change the packaging to "jar", and that made the property substitution work.  It dropped all of our required osgi properties, however.

Comment: wouldn't this better be address on their own jira?

Comment: Which one?  maven-jar-plugin or git-commit-id-plugin?  The point is, this could be an interaction problem.

Comment: well, I would say second - there *has* to be that someone has already tried this. hey, I want to do the same thing when I read your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your update, your problem is regarding `maven-bundle-plugin`.

So you can get rid of the `maven-jar-plugin` and `maven-antrun-plugin` if you don't use them for anything than for the commit id stuff.

Presuming your `maven-bundle-plugin` looks something like this:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.groupId}.${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>Service listener example</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Description>A bundle that displays messages at startup and when service events occur</Bundle-Description>
                        <Bundle-Vendor>Apache Felix</Bundle-Vendor>
                        <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>tutorial.example1.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework</Import-Package>
                        <SCM-Revision>${git.commit.id}, ${gitCommit}</SCM-Revision>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

You can just add your attribute (i.e.`SCM-Revision`) in your `maven-bundle-plugin` your attribute as a `Instruction` in the `<configuration>` section.